# Find the range of value of k for which the function $\frac{(x^2 - 1)}{((x-2)(x+k))}$ where $x$ is real, takes all real values

Tags: functions

Find the range of value of $k$ for which the function $\frac{(x^2 - 1)}{((x-2)(x+k))}$ takes all real values, where is real

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** if $k\in (-1, 1)$, then $\lim_{x\to (-k)^+} f(x) = +\infty$ while $\lim_{x\to 2^-} f(x) = -\infty$, hence $f$ takes all the real values on the interval $(-k, 2)$ in this case.